# In Snowflake Sql: I am trying to display a % sign in my calculated column values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake Sql: I am trying to display a % sign in my calculated column values.
I am trying,

1. (cast((A1/A2 * 100)  as varchar(50))+ '%') as oc. and the error is `Numeric value '%' is not recognized.`
2. (A1/A2)*100+'%'  as oc. and the error is `Numeric value '%' is not recognized.`

I want to display 1.0% , 2.0% in values. Instead of 1, 2 etc.
My formula is A1/A2

Comment: Use `||` for string concatenation, not `+` (which is numeric addition).

Comment: Thanks I want to show results  in round. Again Round(A1/A2)*100 || '%',2) gives similar error

Comment: Again , my statement is ,
(A1/A2)*100+'%'  as oc,
to_varchar(oc, '999.99') || '%'  as oc2
error is : 
SQL compilation error: error line 35 at position 1 too many arguments for function [TO_VARCHAR(A1, '999.99')] expected 1, got 2

I do not see any extra arguments in the syntax

Answer (score 1):

so string/text/varchar concatenation is with [CONCAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html) or `||`

so with simple numbers, the division will give you 6dp:

```
select a1, a2, a1*100/a2 as p, p::text || '%' as oc
from values
    (100, 200)
    ,(1, 100)
    ,(5, 2000)
   -- ,(1, 0)
    t(a1, a2);
```

| A1 | A2 | P | OC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 50 | 50.000000% |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 1.000000% |
| 5 | 2,000 | 0.25 | 0.250000% |

but that divide by zero is tricky, so we can use [DIV0](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/div0.html) and/or [DIV0NULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/div0null.html), which have different handling around null input, at which point we also get to witness how CONCAT will make the whole answer null if any input is null:

```
select a1, a2
    ,div0(a1*100, a2) as p1
    ,p1::text || '%' as oc1
    ,div0null(a1*100, a2) as p2
    ,p2::text || '%' as oc2
from values
    (100, 200)
    ,(1, 100)
    ,(5, 2000)
    ,(1, 0)
    ,(null, 1)
    ,(1, null)
    ,(null, null)
    t(a1, a2);
```

gives:

| A1 | A2 | P1 | OC1 | P2 | OC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 50 | 50.000000% | 50 | 50.000000% |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 1.000000% | 1 | 1.000000% |
| 5 | 2,000 | 0.25 | 0.250000% | 0.25 | 0.250000% |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000% | 0 | 0.000000% |
| null | 1 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | null | null | null | 0 | 0.000000% |
| null | null | null | null | null | null |

lastly there might be the point of formatting the float -> text.

which can be handled with [TO_VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html)

```
select a1, a2
    ,div0(a1*100, a2) as p1
    ,p1::text || '%' as oc1
    ,to_varchar(p1, '999.99') || '%' as oc2
from values
    (100, 200)
    ,(1, 100)
    ,(5, 2000)
    ,(1, 0)
    t(a1, a2);
```

| A1 | A2 | P1 | OC1 | OC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 50 | 50.000000% | 50. % |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 1.000000% | 1. % |
| 5 | 2,000 | 0.25 | 0.250000% | 0.25% |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000% | 0. % |